# Caclulate decile ranking

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table, quantitative-finance

Dataset:

| Date | ticker | overnight_return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-07-20 | CLXT | 0.019556 |
| 2017-07-21 | CLXT | 0.039778 |
| 2022-02-14 | ETNB | -0.006186 |
| 2022-02-15 | ETNB | 0.024590 |

I am testing a hypothesis on the overnight return factor. I want to apply ranking for all unique values in `ticker` column for every `Date`, then z-scoring the ranks. I want to rank them in terms of deciles.

Code to get z-score for one date:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
stats.zscore(equity_daily[equity_daily.Date == "2017-07-20"].overnight_return.rank().dropna().values)
```

To get the z-score for every day based on the rank of all tickers on that particular day I get the pivoted table then create a new table containing the z-scores:

```
equity_daily.pivot(columns = "ticker", values = "overnight_return", index = "Date")
```

But the following error occurred:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Desired outcome:

| Date | ticker | overnight_return | Decile_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-07-20 | CLXT | 0.019556 | 0 |
| 2017-07-21 | CLXT | 0.039778 | 2 |
| 2022-02-14 | ETNB | -0.006186 | 9 |
| 2022-02-15 | ETNB | 0.024590 | 8 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from alphalens.tears import (create_returns_tear_sheet,
                      create_information_tear_sheet,
                      create_turnover_tear_sheet,
                      create_summary_tear_sheet,
                      create_full_tear_sheet,
                      create_event_returns_tear_sheet,
                      create_event_study_tear_sheet)

from alphalens.utils import get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns

def z_score(x):
    """Helper function for Normalization"""
    return stats.zscore(x)

equity_daily["overnight_rank"] = equity_daily.groupby("Date")["overnight_return"].rank(method = "first")
equity_daily["overnight_normalized"] = equity_daily.groupby("Date")["overnight_rank"].apply(z_score)
equity_daily["overnight_normalized"] = equity_daily.overnight_normalized.shift(-1)
equity_daily = equity_daily.dropna()

factor = equity_daily[["Date", "ticker", "overnight_normalized"]].\
                groupby([pd.Grouper(key = "Date"), "ticker"]).sum()

prices = equity_daily.pivot(columns = "ticker", values = "Close", index = "Date")

factor_data = get_clean_factor_and_forward_returns(
    factor = factor,
    prices = prices,
    groupby = None,
    binning_by_group = False,
    quantiles = 10,
    bins = None,
    periods = (1, 5, 10),
    filter_zscore = 20,
    groupby_labels = None,
    max_loss = 0.35
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not having more of a data sample, hard to test myself, but...

Try `pivot_table()` instead of `pivot()`. `pivot` doesn't do aggregations

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have decided to set up helper columns to calculate the decile ranks. However, the pd.qcut() method wouldn't allow duplicated values. Do you have a way to go around?